# How many student do not have interest in football or chess (A set relating problem)

Tags: combinatorics

In a group contains $512$ students, with $170$ student love playing cricket, $85$ students love to play Badminton, $43$ students love to play tennis, $64$ students love to play chess, $128$ students play football and $22$ students play other sports

The question is: How many student does not interest in football or chess ?

When I saw the answer, it is $320$, which I don't thinks I true answer, because i though it must be three case that: (love football but not chess, love chess but not football, and neither of chess and football) - and the number of $320$ is just from subtracting the chess group and football group. Which i don't think is correct, but I don't know how to verify the answer.

Can anyone give me a clear explanation and verify the answer, I am kinda suspicious to the answer to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It appears that there is no overlap because those numbers add up to 512. In that case there are 128 students who play football and 64 who play chess which adds up to 192. Since there are no students who play both,  there are 320 students who neither play football nor play chess.

Comment: thank you so much for your explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$512 (All) = 170 (Cricket) + 85 (Badminton) + 43 (tennis) + 64 (Chess) + 128 (football) + 22 (Other)$

Here the Question takes the Implicit Criteria that no Student has Zero or two or more Sports ; Every Student has Exactly Single Sport ; Hence when we total the Sports , we get the Student Total.

[[ In Case , there are Students with 2 or more Sports , then the total will not work out.
Likewise , when there are Students with no Sports , then the total will not work out. ]]

With that , we can see that $"Chess + football = 0"$ ,  $"Chess + \lnot football = 64"$ ,  $"\lnot Chess + football = 128"$ ,  $"\lnot Chess + \lnot football = X"$ , where we want $X$.

It is obvious that $X = 512-64-128 = 320$
Equivalently $X = 170+85+43+22 = 320$

Comment: thank you for your answer